# MS Graph API issues Access Token after the app is deleted?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I've been poking around MS Graph OAuth2 consent and access token for the enterprise Azure app that had been created along the way. Basically, I'm confused why when I delete the app, I'm still able to obtain the access token ?

When I decrypt and check the claims, it is referencing the name and object id of the deleted app, but it has no roles, and can't be used to access any resources, which makes sense. But still, I'm confused why is being issued for the app that doesn't exist any more ? For example, if I open the app and select to disable login for users, access token is no longer issued - but deleting the whole app does not behave in the same way.

Answer (score 0):

While working with applications in Azure AD, you should be aware of few things like:

- **App Registrations** is where you register an application and configure the details like API permissions, client secrets, client certificates, token claims, app roles etc....
- **Enterprise Applications** are list of service principals that are associated with applications in App Registrations which defines who and what resources the application can access.
- When an app is ***registered*** in Azure AD, it's corresponding service principal will be created with same ***name*** and same ***App ID*** in **`Enterprise Applications`**  blade automatically.

Please **note** that, whatever changes you do to service principal will directly affect the registered application and vice versa.

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the below results:***

I have registered an application in Azure AD and granted permissions like this:

*Go to Azure Active Directory -> App Registrations -> Your App* -> API Permissions

[image]

I generated an access token using client credentials flow, and I can see the ***roles*** claim in decoded token like below:

[image]

Now, I deleted the Enterprise Application of same ***name*** and ***App ID*** like below:

*Go to Azure Active Directory -> Enterprise Applications -> Your Application -> Properties -> Delete*

[image]

After deleting that Enterprise App, I'm still able to generate the access token and can't find ***roles*** claim now like below:

[image]

As the ***service principal*** of the application is deleted, you cannot access the other resources which removes permissions from token.

Please **note** that,

> If you delete the application in **App Registration** first instead of Enterprise App, it will automatically delete the associated **service principal (Enterprise App)** too along with it.

[image]

Then you cannot even generate the access token as it gives **`Unauthorized client - Application not found`** error. Unable to generate access tokens is similar to disabling login for users.

**Reference:**
[Apps & service principals in Azure AD  | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/app-objects-and-service-principals)